# Having issues with posting data using fetch in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch some data from a test API posting some data to it, but I get an error for `response.json()`.
I get no error when fetching data without posting anything from another API.

My JavaScript:

```
fetch('https://cuteweb.ir/translatochka/requests.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
     requestKey: 'checkLogged'
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(parsed => console.log(parsed))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

and here is my API code in PHP:

```
$requestKey = isset($_POST['requestKey'])? $_POST['requestKey']: false;
if($requestKey){
  switch ($requestKey) {
    case 'checkLogged':
      $_SESSION['username'] = "sinaw";
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl_users where 
              username='$_SESSION[username]'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $row['valid'] = true;
                echo json_encode($row);
            }
            break;
```

My API code works correctly as I have tested it with jQuery `$.ajax` method.
This is the error I get:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: `.then(response => response.text()).then(parsed => console.log(parsed))` returns an empty string `" " `. So the response from your server is the problem, as it doesn't return valid json, not the way you make the request.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov if so and my problem is on my server side why would it work correctly with jquery. I removed the `$_POST['requestKey']` part of the code and it worked correctly:/

Comment: Have you checked the network call in the developer console of the browser and checked if the json returned is actually valid? Maybe Jquery parsed it in some way it did work?